# Patterns for unit testing a C++ method that makes a standard library call

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I'm writing a C++ class to wrap sockets (I know that there are good libraries for this--I'm rolling my own for practise):

```
class Socket {
public:
  int init(void); // calls socket(2)
  // other stuff we don't care about for the sake of this code sample
};
```

This class is in turn used by several others, which I know I can unit test with [googlemock](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/) by subclassing and mocking.

But I would like to develop this class [test first](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development), and am a bit stuck currently. I can't use googlemock on the C standard library (i.e. `socket.h`, in this case), since a C++ class it is not. I *could* create a thin C++ wrapper class around the C standard library functions I need, e.g.

```
class LibcWrapper {
public:
   static int socket(int domain, int type, int protocol);
   static int bind(int sockfd, const struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t addrlen);
   static int listen(int sockfd, int backlog);
   static int accept(int sockfd, struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t *addrlen);
   static ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);
   static int close(int fd);
};
```

Now I can mock that and unit test my `Socket` class (which might now need to be renamed `Network` or some such). `LibcWrapper` could come in handy for other classes as well, and would not itself need to be unit tested since it just provides a bunch of class methods.

This is starting to sound good to me. Have I answered my own question, or do there exist standard patterns for test driving this sort of development in C++?

Comment: googlemock [cookbook](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CookBook#Mocking_Free_Functions) suggests something similiar in you case.

Comment: @Beduin: make that an answer and I'll vote it up. :)

Comment: I'm finding, lately, that it's often more meaningful and timewise-effective to verify such classes with integration (?) tests. For example, you could easily verify that your wrapper handles a connection reset by forking a process that 1) connects with raw sockets to your wrapper, running in the main process and then 2) immediately segfaults, causing a connection reset.

Comment: @Andres: I do in fact have a functional test to verify the code that uses my sockets, but what I'm trying to test here is whether a unit of code (i.e. `Network::init()`) calls `socket()`, `Network::listen()` calls `bind()` and `listen()`, and so on, so I think unit tests are called for in addition to a functional test.

Comment: @Josh Glover In that case, I agree 100%. :)

Comment: In case anyone wants more fun: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780747/what-is-wrong-with-my-attempts-to-mock-a-simple-c-method-with-googlemock

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would probably mock it by working through a socket interface (ie base class) and implementing a test version of that base class.

You can do this a couple of ways, for example the simplest thing is to specify the entire socket API in terms of a C++ interface.

```
   class ISocket
   {
   public:
        virtual int socket(int domain, int type, int protocol) = 0;
        virtual int bind(int sockfd...) = 0;
        // listen, accept, write, etc            
   };
```

Then provide a concrete implementation that worked through the BSD sockets library

```
   class CBsdSocketLib : public ISocket
   {
   public:
       // yadda, same stuff but actually call the BSD socket interface
   };


   class CTestSocketLib : public ISocket
   {
   public:
       // simulate the socket library
   };
```

By coding against the interface you can create your test version to do whatever you like.

However, we can clearly see that this first pass is rather weird. We're wrapping an entire library, its not really a class in the sense that it describes objects.

You'd rather think in terms of sockets and ways to manufacture sockets. This would be more object oriented. Along those lines I'd separate the functionality above into two classes.

```
   // responsible for socket creation/construction
   class ISocketFactory
   {
        virtual ISocket* createSocket(...) = 0; // perform socket() and maybe bind()
   };

   // a socket
   class ISocket
   {
         // pure virtual recv, send, listen, close, etc
   };
```

For live use:

```
   class CBsdSocketFactory : public ISocketFactory
   {
      ...
   };

   class CBsdSocket : public ISocket
   { 
      ...
   };
```

For testing:

```
   class CTestSocketFactory : public ISocketFactory
   {
   };

   class CTestSocket : public ISocket
   {
   };
```

And separate the BSD library calls into those two distinct classes that have their own responsibilities.

Comment: I like this approach quite a bit. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I've used that technique as well. Beware that Google Mock doesn't quite support mocking static functions. [The FAQ explains that you should use an interface](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#My_code_calls_a_static/global_function.__Can_I_mock_it?) with virtual methods that you can override in the usual Google Mock way.

Comment: Thanks! I accepted Doug T's example simply because of all the detail he provided, but yours certainly gets the up-vote for the googlemock FAQ link. :)

Answer (score 1):

The Google Mock [cookbook](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CookBook.md) suggests something similar in your case.