# What is wrong with my attempts to mock a simple C++ method with googlemock?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googlemock

As per [Patterns for unit testing a C++ method that makes a standard library call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5779618/patterns-for-unit-testing-a-c-method-that-makes-a-standard-library-call), I'm test-driving development of a network-abstracting class. In order to unit test code that makes standard C library calls (which I can't mock) to handle BSD sockets, I've defined an interface `ISocket` from which both my real implementation `CSocket` and mock `MockSocket` inherit.

Now I write my first unit test for the `Network` class, which uses an `ISocket` for the heavy lifting:

```
#include "gmock/gmock.h"
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
// C standard library includes omitted
#include "MockSocket.h"
#include "Network.h"

using ::testing::Return;
namespace JrStream {
  class NetworkTest : public ::testing::Test {
  protected:
    Network net;
    ISocket * socket_ptr;

    virtual void SetUp() {
      socket_ptr = new MockSocket();
    }
  };

  TEST_F(NetworkTest, InitCallsSocket) {
    EXPECT_CALL((MockSocket)*socket_ptr, Socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))
        .Times(1)
        .WillOnce(Return(5)); //fake file descriptor

    ASSERT_TRUE(net.init(socket_ptr));
  }
} // namespace
// gtest boilerplate main() omitted
```

But I get this error on compilation:

```
g++ -g -Wall -Lgtest-1.5.0/lib -Igmock-1.5.0/include -Igtest-1.5.0/include -I.. -I../../Debug/src -c -o NetworkTest.o NetworkTest.cc
NetworkTest.cc: In member function ‘virtual void JrStream::NetworkTest_InitCallsSocket_Test::TestBody()’:
NetworkTest.cc:35: error: no matching function for call to ‘JrStream::MockSocket::MockSocket(JrStream::ISocket&)’
MockSocket.h:16: note: candidates are: JrStream::MockSocket::MockSocket()
MockSocket.h:16: note:                 JrStream::MockSocket::MockSocket(const JrStream::MockSocket&)
```

And here is what my interface and mock look like:

```
namespace JrStream {
  class ISocket {
    virtual int Socket(int domain, int type, int protocol) = 0;
  };
}

#include "gmock/gmock.h"
#include "ISocket.h"
namespace JrStream {
  class MockSocket: public JrStream::ISocket {
    MOCK_METHOD3(Socket, int(int domain, int type, int protocol));
  };
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it sorted. What was tripping me up is that I wanted to use a pointer, but googlemock works with classes. Here's what works:

```
#include "gmock/gmock.h"
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
// C standard library includes omitted
#include "MockSocket.h"
#include "Network.h"

using ::testing::Return;
namespace JrStream {
  class NetworkTest : public ::testing::Test {
  protected:
    Network net;
    MockSocket sock;
  };

  TEST_F(NetworkTest, InitCallsSocket) {
    EXPECT_CALL(sock, Socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))
        .Times(1)
        .WillOnce(Return(5)); //fake file descriptor

    ASSERT_TRUE(net.init(&sock));
  }
} // namespace
// gtest boilerplate main() omitted
```

This is well and good, but I wonder how to make this work if I really needed my pointers. Sounds like an exercise for the reader. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're invoking the copy constructor for MockSocket  somewhere in TestBody without a cast.

Comment: `(MockSocket)*socket_ptr`... that's a copy.

Comment: OK, that certainly explains the compiler message... now what should my `EXPECT_CALL` look like? gmock doesn't want a pointer--if I say `EXPECT_CALL((MockSocket *)socket_ptr, ...`, the compiler complains: `NetworkTest.cc:35: error: request for member ‘gmock_Socket’ in ‘(JrStream::MockSocket*)((JrStream::NetworkTest_InitCallsSocket_Test*)this)->JrStream::NetworkTest_InitCallsSocket_Test::<anonymous>.JrStream::NetworkTest::socket_ptr’, which is of non-class type ‘JrStream::MockSocket*’`

Comment: Shouldn't it work like that: *static_cast<MockSocket*>(socket_ptr) ?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
TEST_F(NetworkTest, InitCallsSocket) {
EXPECT_CALL(*((MockSocket)*socket_ptr), Socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))
    .Times(1)
    .WillOnce(Return(5)); //fake file descriptor

ASSERT_TRUE(net.init(socket_ptr));
```

}

(Disclaimer - I did not check if it compiles...)